# How can I read integer from file with cmd in c

Tags: c, file-io

This is `input.txt`

```
5343
232
5
```

```
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x;
    int sum=0;
    
    int count=0;
       if(argc==1)
        printf("Error message!");
    if(argc>=2)
    {

    FILE* file = fopen (argv[1], "r");
    
  while(!feof(file)){
    fscanf(file,"%d",&x);
    sum+=x;
        count++;
}
    printf("%d", sum);
    printf("%d", count);
  return 0;
}
```

I use this main and write this in cmd=
c_file.exe input.txt

After that statement in cmd, there is no output and I can't write anything in cmd.

input.txt is given above I want to read and store the integer digit by digit how can I do it?

Comment: Who taught you to use `feof` like that? Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) Use the return value from `scanf` to control the loop. `while(fscanf(file, "%d", &x) == 1)`

Comment: Also, add a newline after every output. `printf("%d\n", sum); printf("%d\n", count);`

Comment: I tried to format the code but there is a closing `}` brace missing somewhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane } brace missing at the end of the line. I tried your solution and doesn't work. It can't break the loop. I rewrite the code and now printing 0 0.

Comment: Always check to make sure `fopen` does not return NULL, indicating failure to open the file at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
  while(fscanf(file,"%d",&x) == 1)
  { 
    sum+=x;
    count++;
  }
```

Comment: it does not enter the loop.

Comment: @rayVel what???